# R squared for K-NN method in R

Tags: r, prediction, knn

We have a data base with predected Y by KNN method , we are looking to estimate the error of the prediction ( Ypredict-Yobserved),  my question is how to calculate R-squared for this type of models in R ? 
Thank you ,

Comment: do you have some working code on how the model is generated in R?

Answer (score 1):

```
preds <- c(1:10)
actual <- c(11:20)

# Residuals sum of squares
rss <- sum((preds - actual) ^ 2)

# Total sum of squares (proportional to the variance of the observed data)
tss <- sum((actual - mean(actual)) ^ 2)

# Coefficient of determination R2
r_square = 1 - (rss/tss)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compute this using the formula from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination)

Since you do not provide any data, I will illustrate with the built-in `mtcars` data. I will write it all out so that it is easy to map to the Wikipedia formula.

```
library(FNN)
TestSample = sample(nrow(mtcars), 5)
## predict values of mpg for the test sample
MTC_KNN = knn.reg(mtcars[-TestSample, -1], 
            mtcars[TestSample, -1], mtcars[-TestSample, 1]) 

## Now compute R-square
SSres = sum((mtcars[TestSample, 1] - MTC_KNN$pred)^2)
SStot = sum((mtcars[TestSample, 1] - mean(mtcars[-TestSample, 1]))^2)
Rsquare = 1 - SSres/SStot
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide data, I mostly just provided some data here. The implementation is similar to the first answer, but you should really use functions for this.

```
       # Y_Predict <- c(1:10)
       #Y_Observed <- c(10:19)



        rss <- function(Y_Predict,Y_Observed)
        {
          return(sum((Y_Predict - Y_Observed) ^ 2))
        }

        tss <- function(Y_Predict,Y_Observed)
        {
          return(sum((Y_Observed - mean(Y_Observed)) ^ 2))
        }


        r_square <- function(rss,tss)
        {
          return(1 - (rss(Y_Predict,Y_Observed)/ tss(Y_Predict,Y_Observed)))
        }

        #Confirming it runs
        # rss(Y_Predict,Y_Observed)
        #tss(Y_Predict,Y_Observed)
        #r_square(Y_Predict,Y_Observed)
```